# Migration Assistant Failing

Tags: time-machine, backup, migration

I'm trying to transfer my information from a mid-2012 Macbook Pro Retina running the latest version of Yosemite (10.10.3). The new machine is a 2015 Retina also running Yosemite.

The first time round I tried doing this via a Thunderbolt cable. The donor machine was booted into target mode, and on the recipient machine I started up the Migration Assistant and followed all the instructions. When the time remaining bar got down to about a minute, it started to creep back up. [image: Info on the screen]

It kept going and going. I left it for an hour and a half (bearing in mind the transfer up until then had taken 20 minutes). It had reached about 17 hours by the time I decided to give up.

I then formatted the drive and reinstalled Yosemite via the Internet. So starting with a clean state I tried again with method 2 which was via a Timemachine backup. This had exactly the same effect. I'm going to leave it overnight in vein hope that something might happen, however I thought that I might as well ask on here to see if there are any suggestions.

This is similar to another question, [New Mac Pro: Setup/Migration Assistant never finishes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161800/new-mac-pro-setup-migration-assistant-never-finishes), and one piece of advice from that is that I should just boot into target mode and manually copy files over. I may well end up doing that, although obviously I don't want to miss anything.

Comment: actually Apple says 

>>Open Migration Assistant, click Continue, then follow the onscreen instructions to transfer info from a Mac.<<

>>Open Migration Assistant on the "other Mac", then follow the onscreen instructions to transfer info to a Mac<<

Comment: @Buscar웃SD that didn't work. Couldn't seem to find the donor Mac on the Thunderbolt cable. Target mode should be no different

Comment: No. Method two was via Ethernet to a time capsule.

Comment: is your disk encrypted on donor ?

Comment: Nope. I've ended up just leaving it in target mode and manually copying stuff over. Bit annoying but done now.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have taken both machines up to 10.10.4 first using the [combo updater](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1820) - as it specifically includes fixes for Migration Assistant.

Then I'd have *followed the instructions* rather than try it in target disk mode - you need to be running Migration Assistant on **both** machines, as you must authorise on both.

I've successfully migrated two machines in the past month, one from 10.10.4 to 10.10.4  ...the other from Windows XP… & if it can do that, it can do anything ;-)

Comment: The Migration Assistant wouldn't recognise the donor machine when connected via a Thunderbolt cable. I did originally follow instructions to the tee. Also the fact that it wouldn't restore via TimeMachine also suggested a problem.